# How to categorize users based on day-to-day using

Tags: terminology, labels

I want to ask for the right terminology for user categories based on their day-to-day use?
for example app:

1. User use the app everyday to get the job done
2. User use the app day after day to get something done
3. User use the app from time to time to get the task done

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question to provide more context? Day to day use of what? An app? Shampoo? Also what are you trying to do that requires categorization of users?

Comment: @nightning see the update

Comment: This seems more like a labeling / English language issue than UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing the correct labels is best left to someone who is familiar with the app; with the client base and who is a native speaker. Ideally he would be a professional writer as well but I'll give it a go.

```
How often do you use this application?

    [ ] I use it multiple times per day for work.
    [ ] I use it several times a week for work.
    [ ] I use it periodically in order to get the task done.
```

EDIT:

As nightning pointed out testing your questions is important. You want the questions to be give useful answers. For that you need (among other things) to remove ambiguity.

Comment: A quick trial run of your question with one or two test users might also be helpful in confirming the wording.

Comment: Yes.  Testing is important.   : )